# Changeable component name in modalica

Tags: openmodelica

I am attempting to use openmodelica to simulate a process plants.

The general method I will be following is to create class type model of the different units and drag and drop these units in OMEdit.

The problem is that I can't find an easy way to change the `defaultComponentName` of each component except by changing it in the code. This is not bad for small systems but for larger systems it may become tedious to search for the new component and change it's name.

Ideally I would like to double click on the component and change it's name in the component parameters window that opens. This will make it a lot easier to use especially for my collages that are not familiar with coding.

To illustrate my point see the diagram below:
[image]

Instead of the name Tank and Tank 1 I need them to reflect their actual plant names eg TK-001 and SU-100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the icon in the diagram and select Attributes.

Comment: Hm, maybe I didn't get the question right and you want to get the name "TK-001" and "SU-100" directly when you drag the classes to the diagram. I guess that's possible if you add annotation(defaultComponentName="TK-001") and annotation(defaultComponentName="SU-100") to those classes.

Comment: I think we should also allow setting the `defaultComponentName` annotation from the GUI.

Comment: @AdeelAsghar: right, we should open a ticket about it :)